# Android imageView drawable lag

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I use https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro repo for make an intro for my android APP.

I have add 3 pictures in `/drawable/` folder.

1. 1024x768 - 123 892 octets - JPG
2. 1024x768 - 98 304 octets - JPG
3. 1024x1024 - 585 728 octets - PNG

But when i switch with my fragment, that's lag a lot. And if i remove this drawable picture, that's work fine...

Do you can try to help me for resolve it please ?

```
 addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Welcome!",
                "This is a demo of the AppIntro library.",
                R.drawable.logov2_intro2,
                Color.parseColor("#616161")));

        addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Clean App Intros",
                "This library offers developers the ability to add clean app intros at the start of their apps.",
                R.drawable.tuto1_jpg,
                Color.parseColor("#1565c0")));

        addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Simple, yet Customizable",
                "The library offers a lot of customization, while keeping it simple for those that like simple.",
                R.drawable.tuto2_jpg,
                Color.parseColor("#1976d2")));

        addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Explore",
                "Feel free to explore the rest of the library demo!",
                R.drawable.logov2_intro2,
                Color.parseColor("#616161")));
```

Thanks

Comment: The images seem to be quite big. Can you use smaller images?

Comment: Oh, it's just this. I've reduce -50% all the picture, that's work fine. Sorry for this question :) And thanks :p